# Chromium Won't Run on Ubuntu 12.04 with Remote Desktop VNC (Works on 10.04)

Tags: chromium, vnc

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit VPS with 512MB of Ram and a 15GB HDD. On separate, fresh/new VPS servers, I've installed LXDE, Lubuntu and Xubuntu using tightvnc - on separate VPS server. On all occasions I am unable to use Chromium.

Edit: I tried LXDE on Ubuntu 10.04 and everything is working. This seems to be an issue on Ubuntu 12.04.

To clarify, these are remote VPS servers that I VNC into. There is no monitor installed on the remote machine.

I click the icon to launch Chromium, an purple-ish color screen pops up as it tries to launch, and then in a split second later, it crashes. Sometimes I can see the Chromium address bar, tabs, etc for a brief moment as it tries to run.

If I try to run from the command line I get:

```
chromium-browser
Xlib extension “RANDR” missing on display ":1"
```

On random instances, Chromium will try to send a crash report. In those notes I noticed this...

```
can't open profile /home/user1/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences
```

I looked in that folder and indeed there is no Preferences folder. So I create a `Preferences` folder, try to run Chromium and the folder is renamed `Preferences.bad`.

I then delete the entire `Default` folder, tried to launch Chromium and a new `Default` folder is created. Chromium crashes and still no Preferences folder is created within that new Default folder.

Seems maybe there is a permissions issue or something, but I can't put my finger on it. Here is exactly how I install these desktop environments, step-by-step. Maybe you can see something I'm doing wrong.

I deploy new 64-bit Ubuntu VPS. I SSH into the server as root and run the following commands...

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install lubuntu tightvncserver
```

I then add a VNC user and set passwords...

```
adduser user1
su - user1
vncpasswd
exit
```

As root, I edit `/etc/init.d/vncserver`

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin/"
export USER="user1"
DISPLAY="1"
DEPTH="16"
GEOMETRY="1024x768"
OPTIONS="-depth ${DEPTH} -geometry ${GEOMETRY} :${DISPLAY}"
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

case "$1" in
start)
log_action_begin_msg "Starting vncserver for user '${USER}' on localhost:${DISPLAY}"
su ${USER} -c "/usr/bin/vncserver ${OPTIONS}"
;;

stop)
log_action_begin_msg "Stoping vncserver for user '${USER}' on localhost:${DISPLAY}"
su ${USER} -c "/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :${DISPLAY}"
;;

restart)
$0 stop
$0 start
;;
esac
exit 0
```

edit home `/home/user1/.vnc/xstartup` and for this example I add (for lubuntu):

```
#!/bin/sh

#xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey

#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#x-window-manager &

export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
autocutsel -fork
openbox &
/usr/bin/lxsession -s Lubuntu -e LXDE &
```

Update file permissions to allow users to start X Server

```
chown -R user1. /home/user1/.vnc && chmod +x /home/user1/.vnc/xstartup
sed -i 's/allowed_users.*/allowed_users=anybody/g' /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config
```

Make `/etc/init.d/vncserver` executable and start VNC server:

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/vncserver && service vncserver start
```

Add VNC server to automatically start on reboot:

```
update-rc.d vncserver defaults
```

I then start TightVNC Viewer on my Windows machine and enter theserverip::5901 to access the desktop.

I've also tried installing the desktop environment with xrdp and rdp into the desktop as root, and same issue. So I think that eliminates issues with tightvnc.

There seems to be no issues with any other applications on the dekstop. Firefox works just fine, but unfortunately I need to make Chromium work in this case.

Is there something I'm doing wrong with my setup?

Comment: I noticed on my local PC running xubuntu on VirtualBox that there is no Profiles folder in Chromium either, however Chromium runs fine in this environment. So must be something else going on here.

Comment: Installed lubuntu on virtualbox running my local machine and chromium runs just fine, so something definitely strange going on here.

Comment: Tried with Ubuntu 10.04 and everything is working. Must be something to do with Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Braiam, yes I restarted the server with no luck. Edited the original question as you suggested. Thanks!